# How to export MVC webgrid results to pdf and excel directly without using any third party control?(iTEXtSharp i not working)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have tried itextsharp samples and the serializing to xml .
Am using Entity frame work 6.0 
and asp.net mvc4

Comment: Please explain why iTextSharp is not working for you. Show us the code you tried and give any errors you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using following for export to excel:

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
        {
            var datasource = db.Products.ToList(); 

            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = datasource;         
            gv.DataBind();            
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

           return Json("Success");
           }
```

In View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {           

  <button type="Submit">Export to Excel</button>
            }

//OR:

@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportData", "Home")
```

As to export to PDF, I'd recommend to use [Rotativa](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335595/Rotativa-how-to-print-PDF-in-Asp-Net-MVC). Works ok for me.

**EDITED**
I'm using filters too. You may send it's value from `View` to `controller action` and modify `datasource`. For example:

```
public ActionResult ExportData(DateTime fromDate)
            {
                var datasource = db.Products.Where(g=>g.Date <= fromDate).ToList();
```

Comment: am populating the data in MVC Webgrid with some filters is there any approach the only populated(binded ) data of wegrid data to export dynamically. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes I can able to export the data to excel by using gridview but in my web page am displaying the data in webgrid the data what ever I populated want to export to excel randomly. in one action method of controller instead of having different action method for populating data into WEBGRID and one more action method for exporting data using GRIDVIEW.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

var data = GetFeedbackDetailsExport();

```
            var gridWeb = new WebGrid(source: data, canPage: false, canSort: false);
            string exportData = gridWeb.GetHtml(
                            columns: gridWeb.Columns(
                                                  gridWeb.Column("EnterpriseId", "EnterpriseId"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("GroupName", "Group Name"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("Geography", "Geography"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("Country", "Country"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("DeliveryCentre", "Delivery Centre"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("Vendor", "Vendor Name"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("Category", "Category"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("ModelName", "ModelName"),                                            
                                                  gridWeb.Column("Status", "Status"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("Date_Submitted", "Submitted On", format: (item) => item.Date_Submitted != null ? item.Date_Submitted.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") : ""),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("UpdatedBy", "Feedback Given By", style: "col-lg-1"),
                                                  gridWeb.Column("UpdatedOn", "Feedback Given On", format: (item) => item.UpdatedOn != null ? item.UpdatedOn.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") : "")
                 )
                                ).ToHtmlString();
            return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(exportData),
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                    "FeedbackReport.xls");
```